# Returning Multi-Dimensional char* Array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, data-structures, char

I am developing a utility DLL for a trading tool (MultiCharts). The library needs to be built in C++ for the tool to use it. My problem is that I need to write a method that can return a multi-dimensional array of type: `char*`. The reason for using `char*` and not string is that the tool is not compatible with the string datatype. So `char*` (which is compatible) has to be used.

I have researched a little bit and have found some code snippets but none seem to be working for me.

```
char ***signals = new char**[1024];

for (int i=0; i<data.size(); i++)
{
    signals[i] = new char*[8];

    for (int j=0; j<8; j++)
    {
        string instance;
        char* result;

        instance = data[i][j];

        result = new char[instance.size() + 1];
        result[instance.size()] = 0;
        memcpy(result, instance.c_str(), instance.size());

        signals[i][j] = result;
    } 
}
```

The above snippet doesn't properly work and only garbage values are stored. I ran it as a console application; and here is the screenshot of the debugging information:

[image]

The data structure created can have total rows = 1024 and 8 columns (system's requirement). **data** used here is a vector which has the values that need to be transferred to the tool.

Anyone has any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: In C++, don't return `char ***`. Return `vector<vector<string> >`.

Comment: where did you debug the char values stored, in release mode?

Comment: @H2CO3 Thank you for your comment. As i mentioned, i have this constraint that wouldn't let me return string data-type. That is why i need to use char*.

Comment: @thomas no. I did it in debug mode.

Comment: @Master.Aurora OK, I understand. I don't really see anything wrong with the code, but let me try it.

Answer (score 0):

Awful as it is, this code seems correct. And your picture does NOT imply garbage, it shows a healthy string.

Your problem is probably elsewhere.

On the other part: C-style array can not be returned from a function. But you can return a char ***.